# Disabling jquery ui dialog buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i disable the jquery UI dialog buttons like :

```
   $("#dialog").dialog({ width: 500, modal: true, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
        buttons: {
            "Next": function () {/* do something */ },
            "Finish" : function {/* do something */ } 
        }
    });
```

I want to keep `disabled the Next button` until user selects some `radio button or checkbox` and when user will select any of then `'Next button will enabled'`. (Same behavior which we can see when we install any new software.).How can i do this?

Comment: I assume they have a set `id` or `class`, just set some event listeners with `.on` or `.live` (depending on jQuery version) calling for a validation/check function, it can't be that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebug or inspect element from google chrome then find next button id or css rule... I mean a correct selector to the button then you can always call

```
$("Nextbutton selector").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

re enable by

```
$("Nextbutton selector").removeAttr('disabled');
```

hope this help

PS:
When inspect i saw

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Next</span>
</button>
```

so you can call

```
$('button.ui-button:contains("Next")').attr....
```

Comment: but how we can give the id to `dialog`s Next button`

Comment: Jquery usually do that itself, you cant change that

Comment: I just suggest a selector, can you try?

Answer (score 0):

To enable:

```
$(e.currentTarget).button( "option", "disabled", false );
```

To disable:

```
$(e.currentTarget).button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

[Button Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Right after creating and opening the dialog, which is what this (your code) does:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({ width: 500, modal: true, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
    buttons: {
        "Next": function () {/* do something */ },
        "Finish" : function {/* do something */ } 
    }
 });
```

Do this:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog('widget')
     .find("button :contains('Next')").parent().button("disable");
```

It will immediately disable the "Next" button.  When ready, you can enable the button by doing:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog('widget')
     .find("button :contains('Next')").parent().button("enable");
```